# Flex on Android: App screen goes black when the soft keyboard pops up

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have an odd random problem in my Flex app for an android tablet (Samsung Note 10.1).

Sometimes (it is really random) when i click on a TextInput and the SoftKeyboard pops up, the whole screen goes black. Once it happened, it will go black every time I click on a TextInput. If i restart the application, everything is fine again.

My setup: Flex SDK 4.13.0 + AIR 14.0
The TextInput is not using any skins, just the default
RenderingMode: CPU (Can't use GPU)

Comment: Have you use? spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin

Comment: Or use. ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.StageTextInputSkin");

Comment: Is it the whole screen of your application or only just the softkeyboard area? Check any softkeyboard listeners are there in your app that cause the problem or try with different sdk's (may be older) and also build with different flash playerVersion.

Comment: The whole screen goes black. No, there are no listeners or anything. Worked fine all the time until we've switched to the new SDK. Thanks for the hints guys, i will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm still not 100% sure if that problem have been solved but it didn't appeared for a long time after i've tried two things:

1. My app was using the Camera and I've read somewhere that the Camera have caused similar problems for some people. Indeed it turned out that the camera was not detached properly in my code. This did not helped in my case but maybe it will help someone else
2. I have found this hack in some third party component code (don't remember where) and apparently it did help. Basically, it is switching the app quality back and forth forcing Flex to redraw. So in your main MXML place this code after "addedToStage" event:

   ```
   private function onAddedToStage():void
   {
       //Workaround for blank screen after screen unlock.
       stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, function(e:Event):void
       {
           stage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM;
       });
       stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, function(e:Event):void
       {
           stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
       });
   }
   ```